# How to trigger a Google Cloud Build job periodically from Google cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-scheduler

I configured a cloud schedular job following [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run)

But find error `status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"`. did not understand from where it came from. any suggestion to fix this, would be grateful.

Comment: You might want to post some code for us to look at. Without it, there's no way we can diagnose what the problem is. If you're using curl, then post the curl command you're running. If it's in a script, post the script code.

Comment: There is no code. That is a cloud scheduler function for triggering a cloud build job.

Comment: Huh, the only thing I can think is if the project ID is incorrect, or if the triggerId is misspelt? Double check that the project ID is actually the ID and not the project name? (I've done this more than once)

Comment: Hey. Checked the project ID as you say. -- `https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxIDxxx/triggers/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx:run` problem persists.

Comment: Yah, that LOOKS right to me...lemme poke some teammates and see if they have thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow the bellow steps to trigger:

1.- Create a new [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and add the "Cloud Build Service Account" and "Cloud Scheduler Service Agent" roles to it.

2.- The HTTP method should be "post".

3.- You must specify in the body field the "repoName" and the "branchName". Use the below as example.

```
{
  "repoName": "MyRepo",
  "branchName": "MyBranch"
}
```

4.- Select "Add OAuth token" as Auth header.

5.-Assign the created SA to your Cloud Scheduler Job that want to use to trigger your cloud Build job.

6.-Use this value "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" as Scope

Once you have these changes, you will be able to execute the trigger.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I think I messed with BODY field.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where the body JSON is documented?