# how to build a yaml file to run my python code

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

Hi everyone and sorry for the silly question but its my day 2 with Yaml.

- Problem statement: 
  I have a python code which runs for 12 mins, (so I cant use Cloud Function to automate it), hence using cloud build as a hack.
- Steps done so far: 
  I have my code in google cloud repository and I used cloud build to build an image and created a google cloud build trigger. Now I want to run the main.py python code each time I trigger the build ( which I will do using a Cloud Scheduler as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682555/how-to-trigger-a-google-cloud-build-job-periodically-from-google-cloud-scheduler)
- Folder structure (as shown in the image below)

[image: Folder structure in cloud repo]

- cloudbuild.yaml which I managed to write so far

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/p2p-cloudbuild' 
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c','virtualenv /workspace/venv' ]
  # Create a Python virtualenv stored in /workspace/venv that will persist across container runs.

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/p2p-cloudbuild' 
  entrypoint: 'venv/bin/pip'
  args: ['install', '-V', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
  # Installs any dependencies listed in the project's requirements.txt.
```

Question : How do I add the step to call/execute 'my_function' inside main.py file ?

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/p2p-cloudbuild' 
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: ['-c','virtualenv /workspace/venv' ]
  # Create a Python virtualenv stored in /workspace/venv that will persist across container runs.

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/p2p-cloudbuild' 
  entrypoint: 'venv/bin/pip'
  args: ['install', '-V', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
  # Installs any dependencies listed in the project's requirements.txt.
```

Let's say I have a file `main.py`:

```
def foo():
  return "bar"
```

This actually can be simplified into:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/p2p-cloudbuild' 
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      virtualenv /workspace/venv
      source /workspace/venv/bin/activate
      pip install -V -r requirements.txt
      python -c 'from main import foo; print (foo())'
```